# How to Fix regular expression capturing group error Bigquery?

Tags: regex, re2

I am trying to move code from SQL server to Bigquery but I am having trouble with certain columns in my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
       CAST(regexp_extract(local_chores, '([^&]+)&([^&]+)&.*', 1) as string) as origin_place_code,
      CAST(regexp_extract(local_chores, '([^&]+)&([^&]+)&.*', 2) as string) as origin_equipment_code,
```

I get an error :  ***Regular expressions passed into extraction functions must not have more than 1 capturing group***

I tried to play around with my code but I didn't manage to fix the error. Does anyone have insight into this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(local_chores, r'([^&]+)&[^&]+&.*') AS origin_place_code,
       REGEXP_EXTRACT(local_chores, r'[^&]+&([^&]+)&.*') AS origin_equipment_code,
  FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

[`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) function requires extracting one capturing group from the text.

There are two capturing groups in your regular expression.

You might want to check the expression with https://regexr.com/

[image]

[image]